# Defining a bounded operator on $l^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, lp-spaces

Let $(c_{jk})_{j,k \in \mathbb{N}} \subset \mathbb{C}$ be such that $a:=\sup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}}|c_{jk}|<\infty$ and $b:=\sup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}}|c_{jk}|<\infty$ Prove that $$T:l^p \to l^p,(Tx)_j:=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}}c_{jk}x_k$$ defines a bounded linear map with $\|T\|\leq a^{\frac{1}{p}}b^{\frac{1}{q}}$ where $p \in (1,\infty)$ and $q$ is its Hölder conjugate

I have spent a couple of hours trying to prove this inequality but nothing seems to be working . I can't even prove that T is a bounded operator. Any hints on how could I go about solving this ? I started by writing the definition of the norm as

$\|T\|=\sup_{\|x\|_{p}=1}\big(\|Tx\|\big)=\sup_{\|x\|_{p}=1}\big(\sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \big(\sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}}c_{jk}x_k \big)^{p} \big)^{1/p}$
Then I tried to use Holder's inequality  inside bracket but nothing seems to be working . I mean I can try to write down what i tried to do, but none of my attempts seem to go anywhere
Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: The definition of $T$ seems wrong -- namely, the summation index should probably be $k$, not $j$.

Comment: @ClementC.My bad!.Ofcourse you are right!!Thanks for pointing out the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that 
$$|T(x)(j)|^p \leqslant \left(\sum_{l\in\mathbf N}|c_{j,l}|   \right)^p \left(\sum_{k\in\mathbf N} \alpha_{j,k}|x_k|    \right)^p,$$
where 
$$\alpha_{j,k}=\frac{|c_{j,k}|}{\sum_{l\in\mathbf N}|c_{j,l}|},$$
hence by Jensen's inequality, 
$$|T(x)(j)|^p \leqslant \left(\sum_{l\in\mathbf N}|c_{j,l}|   \right)^p \sum_{k\in\mathbf N} \alpha_{j,k}|x_k|^p=\left(\sum_{l\in\mathbf N}|c_{j,l}|   \right)^{p-1} \sum_{k\in\mathbf N} |c_{j,k} ||x_k|^p \leqslant b^{p-1} \sum_{k\in\mathbf N} |c_{j,k}||x_k|^p.$$
Using the definition of $a$, we derive the bound 
$$\sum_{j\in\mathbf N} |T(x)(j)|^p \leqslant b^{p-1}a\lVert x\rVert_p^p.$$

Comment: The last step follows because we can interchange the two summations(by applying fubini-tonelli as the summands are all positive right?. I mean $\sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}}b^{p-1} \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}}|c_{jk}||x_k|^p=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}}b^{p-1} \big( \sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}} |c_{jk}||x_k|^p<ab^{p-1} \big) \sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} |x_k|^p=b^{p-1}a \|x\|^p$

Comment: sorry for the misplaced bracket, i was editing it but they locked it, the bracket is suppose to close before the $|x_k|^p$

Comment: Yes, we indeed need to interchange the summation.